# How to create a release tag using .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: tags, release, gitlab-ci

I need to run jobB only when jobA passes. I have to create a release tag only when my test stage passes successfully (I have added a code for that to happen here). My repository has 'README.md' file already. I am just checking its existence in my test stage. So, my test stage will always pass. Please let me know how do I write a code to create a release tag. A tag can be for example v1.1

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

jobA:
  stage: test
  script:
    - test -e README.md && exit 0

jobB:
  stage: release
  when: on_success
  script:
 # code for creating a release tag
```

Comment: You could use the REST API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/index.html#create-a-release

Comment: Also there is this command line tool provided by Gitlab itself: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli

Answer (score 2):

In addition of [Greg Woz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2170368/greg-woz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61541249/6309), in which `GITLAB_API_TOKEN` (a [PAT -- PErsonal Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)) is used, you now can also use a dedicated private *project* token:

See [GitLab 13.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/#support-private-token-to-create-releases-using-the-release-cli) (February 2021)

> ### Support PRIVATE-TOKEN to create releases using the Release-CLI
>
> In this milestone, we added the ability to use the `release-cli` with a `PRIVATE-TOKEN` as defined in the [Create a release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#create-a-release) API documentation.
>
> This enables overriding the user that creates a release, and supports automation by allowing connection of a project-level `PRIVATE-TOKEN` or by using a bot user account’s `PRIVATE-TOKEN`.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#create-a-release) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/issues/11).

Answer (score 1):

It may not answer fully for your question but hopefully it helps. Perhaps try the below. My solution assumes you have `package.json` with version as it's the most popular case - but there is nothing wrong if you use any other way to define version:

```
version:
  stage: version
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - VERSION_NUMBER=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
    - "curl --header \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_API_TOKEN\" --request POST  \"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/tags?tag_name=v${VERSION_NUMBER}&ref=$CI_COMMIT_SHA&message=Tagged%20with%20version%20v${VERSION_NUMBER}\""
```

Then you can use:

```
publish:
  stage: publish
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - npm version --no-git-tag-version ${CI_COMMIT_TAG:1}
    - npm publish --access public
```

for example in a next step.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab 13.2 introduced [release keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release) in .gitlab-ci.yml. There's no need anymore to create a "jobB" job, you can add keyword to main job as long as it can access release-cli:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

jobA:
  stage: test
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - test -e README.md && exit 0
  release:
    tag_name: $TAG
    description: './path/to/CHANGELOG.md'
```

GitLab Docs has [some examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cicd_examples.html) to dynamically provide $TAG and description.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#dependencies) mechanism is a right tool for doing that. So, you can use README.MD (or test results folder) as an artifact in **jobA** and add the dependency on **jobA** in the **jobB**

`jobB:
....
  dependencies:
    - jobA`

If the **jobA** fail it won't provide dependent artifact for **jobB**. Thus, it also will fail.

**(Edit)**
Have you checked **Protected tags** gitlab settings? (Settings -> Repository -> Protected tags)
Default settings are:

> By default, protected tags are designed to:
>
> Prevent tag creation by everybody except Maintainers
>
> Prevent anyone from updating the tag
>
> Prevent anyone from deleting the tag

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. In my code, the dependency is established using "when: on_success". I am not able to create a tag or release using my gitlab-ci.yml file.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question. So, you have the code for creating a release tag, right?

Comment: No, I want to write a code for release (creating tag). I dont know how it can be done. I tried by using Gitlab Release API, pushing git tags and create a release of that git. But its not allowing me to push tags from .gitlb-ci.yml.

Comment: Probably it's an issue with "protected tags" setting. Please check the edited part of the answer

Comment: yes, I had also changed my settings in protected tags, but still, this is not working. May be its about permissions to push tags by gitlab-runner.

Comment: It got running. I am able to create tags. But now, for one commit only, pipeline is running many times :(

Comment: You can try to turn off job execution for tags. [check only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic)
for example: `jobA: except: - tags`